# Установка пакетов в открытую в данный момент папку на MacOS?

Tags: macos, mac, терминал

Как настроить терминал MacOS таким образом, чтобы он показывал в какой папке ты сейчас находишься и соответственно устанавливал пакеты в открытую папку с проектом, а не в домашнюю директорию типа `/users/name` ?

Comment: Директория указывается перед именем пользователя, если я правильно понял https://imgur.com/a/038iRNB

Answer (score 0):

В ваш ~/.profile (а если есть .bashrc то лучше в него) добавьте.

```
Colorized_PS1 () {
    local RED GREEN RESET HOST_C WD_C USER_C ENDL

    RED='\[\033[31m\]'
    GREEN='\[\033[32m\]'
    RESET='\[\033[0m\]'

    HOST_C='\[\033[34m\]'
    USER_C="${GREEN}"
    WD_C='\[\033[33m\]'
    ENDL='$'
    [[ $(whoami) == "root" ]] && HOST_C="${RED}" && USER_C="${RED}" && ENDL='#'

    printf '%s' "[ \\A ] [ ${WD_C}\\w${RESET} ]\\n[ ${USER_C}\\u${RESET}@${HOST_C}\\H${RESET} ]${USER_C}${ENDL}${RESET}: "
}
PS1=$(Colorized_PS1)
```

Получится вот так:
[image: Результат]

С расцветкой тоже можно поиграться но это уже другая история